# Debugging not working in Intellij - NodeJS + NestJS App

Tags: node.js, debugging, intellij-idea

I am trying to debug a nodejs + nest application in IntelliJ, I am able to start the application using two types of configs.

1. Using Yarn (through NPM configuration template in intellij)
2. Using Node (I am not sure but when I use the main.js from dist folder then I get some debug point but it is useless as it is not pointing to my actual code base)

Debugger doesn't work for any of the above options!

I am posting screen shots of both the configurations.

New to Node + IntelliJ, so not sure what did I do wrong in both the configurations! Any help would be appreciated.

Intellij Version is 2020.3.3 And NodeJS application exposes several APIs, I am trying to call the APIs using a Postman and expect it to debug.

[image: NPM Debug Configuration]

[image: Node Debug Config]

Answer (score 14):

Debugging in both `main.ts` and controllers works for me when using the configuration below:

[image]

[image]

See also https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/993 for some recipes

Comment: tanks a lot, it works with `-r ts-node/register -r tsconfig-paths/register`

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify what "the configuration below" is. Image-only content is not accessible or usable for everyone. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Comment: This worked for me too, I wanted to debug a NestJS application with IntelliJ and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter/issues/165

Add two run/debug configurations in webstorm:

- npm run start:debug
- Attach to Node.js/Chrome - `Host`: `localhost`, `Port`: `9229`.

Then click "Run" button to start the first configuration, and click "Debug" button to start the second configuration.

Answer (score 1):

May be go to package.json and u will see options here, click on the option of either to run or debug.
[image: package.json]